# FFmpeg throws error: "No decoder for stream #0:1, filtering impossible"

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

When i try to convert a .mov to .mp4, I get an error: `No decoder for stream #0:1, filtering impossible`

[image]

Comment: It seems ffmpeg was compiled without svq1 support.

Comment: how can i resolve it

Comment: compile it with svq1 support

Comment: Do i need to install any ext on server

Comment: @IporSircer  The issue is audio decoding of codec QDMC, not video. Looks like it's only possible on OS X.

Comment: Okey, sorry. Then compile with qdmc_at.

Comment: Answered at [FFMPEG Unable to Decode Quicktime QDMC Stream (No decoder for stream)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801421/ffmpeg-unable-to-decode-quicktime-qdmc-stream-no-decoder-for-stream).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue (with .mov and shq2 encoding :) ), It turns out I just had to grab the latest ffmpeg... As time passes, ffmpeg list of supported (de)coders increases...